# Putting calcuting result into another array

Tags: javascript

I've an array in object which has 5 elements. With help of for loop I want to select this elements which has less than 50 and multiply them by 0.2. At the end I want to push these results to my empty tipArray but it doesn't work.

```
var bill = {
  tipArray: [],
  billValue: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tipValue: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.billValue.length; i++) {
      if (this.billValue[i] < 50) {
        var enumerate = this.billValue[i] * .2;
        this.tipArray.push(enumerate);
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(bill.tipArray);
```

Comment: You have to call `tip.tipValue()` ?

Comment: please add the wanted result. actually i have seen this kind of question at least two times ... what is with the answers to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you format your code correctly? It's hard to read. You have to run the function `tipValue` at least once.

```
var bill = {...};

bill.tipValue();

console.log(bill.tipArray); // [9.600000000000001, 8.4]
```